# Как исправить ошибку когда я пытаюсь создать/использовать Modal? (код и ошибка есть в описании)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, modal

**Код:**

```py
# пытаюсь сделать так что бы участник вводил что-то в всплывающем окне 
class MyModal(discord.ui.Modal, title='Title'):
    answer = discord.ui.TextInput(label='Name', style=discord.TextStyle.short, placeholder='PlaceHolder', max_length=15)


    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        embed = discord.Embed(title=self.title, description=f"**{self.answer.label}**\n{self.answer}.", color=discord.Color.blue)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)

# кнопка для вызова MyModal()
class Menu(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @discord.ui.button(label='Отправить сообщение', style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray)
    async def menu1(self, interaction:discord.Interaction, button:discord.ui.Button):
        modal = MyModal()
        await interaction.response.send_modal(modal=modal)


# вызов команды которая по идеи должна запрашивать у пользователя что-то
@bot.command()
async def modal(ctx):
    view = Menu()
    await ctx.send('Hi', view=view)
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
ERROR   discord.ui.view Ignoring exception in view <Menu timeout=180.0 children=1> for item <Button style=<ButtonStyle.secondary: 2> url=None disabled=False label='Отправить сообщение' emoji=None row=None>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 425, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  
File "c:\Users\User1\Documents\Discord_Bots\Tiket_bot\main.py", line 119, in menu1
    await interaction.response.send_modal(modal=modal)

TypeError: InteractionResponse.send_modal() got some positional-only arguments passed as keyword arguments: 'modal'
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашей строке ошибка:

```
        await interaction.response.send_modal(modal=modal)
```

Уберите `modal=`:

```
        modal = MyModal()
        await interaction.response.send_modal(modal)
```